# Test predictions are all the same

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to build a Keras model with binary outputs for a recommendation task.

After I build it and train it, it seems to be converging and improving both training and validation accuracy:

```
EPOCH:  0
Train on 4641920 samples, validate on 1160480 samples
Epoch 1/1
4641920/4641920 [==============================] - 93s 20us/step - loss: 0.0317 - val_loss: 0.0262
TRAIN F1:  0.16175450762829402
VAL F1:  0.09613703897919944
EPOCH:  1
Train on 4641920 samples, validate on 1160480 samples
Epoch 1/1
4641920/4641920 [==============================] - 100s 22us/step - loss: 0.0238 - val_loss: 0.0256
TRAIN F1:  0.2667970500753779
VAL F1:  0.1608853650479022
```

But when I try to predict the values in the test set, it outputs only 0s (there seems to be no such problem with validation set however):

```
val_prediction = model.predict(x=[val_customer_id, val_vendor_id], verbose=1, batch_size=384)
print(np.unique(val_prediction.round()))

1160480/1160480 [==============================] - 6s 5us/step
    [0. 1.]



val_prediction = model.predict(x=[test_customer_id, test_vendor_id], verbose=1, batch_size=384)
print(np.unique(val_prediction.round()))

1672000/1672000 [==============================] - 8s 5us/step
[0.]
```

I'm really struggling here and it would be really helpful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible reasons:

1- If your train and test sets are too sparse, then you will get a bad accuracy on the test set

2- Your model is overfitting.

Answer 1:

If the dataset is too sparse, you need to rearrange them. Try adding some validation values to test, see if the result is changing.

Answer 2:

If your model is overfitting:

a- Adding new layers

b- Dropout

c- Increasing batch size

may solve your problems.

Comment: If my model is overfitting, wouldn't the Validation predictions be all wrong as well?

Comment: No. Since you have selected your validation data from the training set, your model performs well. https://towardsdatascience.com/what-are-overfitting-and-underfitting-in-machine-learning-a96b30864690